# Marketing Cloud Microsite

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites

My use case:

Currently we have an admin console on a cloud page landing page which has no security, technically if someone has the link they can edit the admin console.

From my understanding, if we move this to a classic content microsite, we can set the security to "System Authenticated Redirection" which would re-direct users that are not logged in, into a log-in page.

The problem I am having is that the documentation surrounding microsites is very lackluster.

I have created a microsite but am seeing nowhere to save the html for the microsite and when attempting to load the microsite it just states "The page you have requested is unavailable!"

What are the proper steps to create a microsite?

edit:
[image]

I am clicking on "IHS Outreach PCRM Config", after clicking on that nothing loads

it displays such as:

[image]

Are there any possible permissions I am missing? I am an admin on the system.

Edit2: Although if i check the box and hit properties, this loads.

[image]

Comment: I would steer away from using Classic Content Mircrosites as they are going to be sunset in the next year or so. I would recommend creating your own authorization system for the cloud page. A very simple example would be to have user/pass combinations stored inside of a DE and use an HTML form as a 'login' page.

Comment: @Gortonington While I agree CloudPages are the future, Classic Microsites will not be sunset anytime soon (from the docs: "[The end of support plan for classic content does not affect Microsites and Landing Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_microsites.htm&type=5)"). Creating a secure and reliable authorization system from scratch using AMPscript/SSJS is not a trivial undertaking for an SFMC novice, IMO. If System Authenticated Redirection is enabled and ready to go for the asker, might as well use it today.

Comment: @MarkG I am attempting to use the microsites, but am not seeing the correct steps to setting one up. I have one created but am unable to see any place to publish it or change the html code for one. Any suggestions?

Comment: I may have misspoke. By sunset I mean no longer supported. As in there will not be any implementation or consideration for them in new features and support.  Plus any updates, etc. to platform may cause 'bugs' or similar inside these pages. Think of it similar to Windows 95. Can you still use it? Sure. Is it efficient and low risk? No. The authorization system you speak of for Microsites needs to be turned on by SFMC Global support. It requires the user to log into their SFMC account in order to be able to access the page. This means that each user needs an SFMC account.

Comment: @TimWillis Steps provided below. Additionally, gortonington makes a good point about your SAR-secured microsite being accessible only to those who also have an SFMC login to the account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to classic microsites: the (1) microsite itself and the (2) microsite definition.

**Part One**

1. From the top, navigate to **Content**

[image]

2. From the left, navigate to **My Microsites**

[image]

3. Create a new Microsite

[image]

4. Enter your microsite's properties then **Save** (whether to "Auto Publish" or not is up to you; more on this later at the end of **Part Two**)

[image]

5. Create a new HTML landing page

[image]

6. Build from HTML (i.e., hand-code/paste) and give it a name

[image]

7. Set the Character Set, Content Type, and Security properties (HTML Doctype doesn't apply as we're not using a template) then **Save**

[image]

8. Enter some HTML code then **Save**

[image]

*At this point, while the landing page has been created, it'll be unavailable until a Microsite Definition is created.*

**Part Two**

9. From the top, navigate to **Interactions**

[image]

10. From the left, navigate to **My Microsites**

[image]

11. Create a new Microsite Definition

[image]

12. Enter a name and external key

[image]

13. Select the source microsite then **Save**

[image]

14. Check the box next to the microsite definition then click "**Start/Restart**"

[image]

15. Access the landing page from a browser and it should now be available. You'll receive a "page unavailable" message if the Microsite Definition hasn't been setup or is paused.

[image]

Note: If you did not set your microsite to "Auto Publish" (Part One, step 4), every time you make a change to your landing page(s), you'll instead need to "**Pause**" your Microsite Definition first, then "**Publish**", then finally click "**Start/Restart**" before those changes are reflected.

Comment: Hello, So I have followed up until step 8 but am not seeing any place to insert html code? when I click on the microsite landing page name, it doesn't load anything, I have tried this on 2 seperate pcs

Comment: @TimWillis Are you sure you're clicking the **microsite** name ("Hello" in the example) first which will display a list of all contained landing pages... and then clicking the **landing page** name from that list ("Home" in the example) after? I would also check with your admin if you have all the correct permissions for microsites enabled.

Comment: I edited the main post with images

Comment: @TimWillis In your last screenshot, click the "Edit" link (next to the pencil icon).

Comment: Same problem, nothing loads

Comment: @TimWillis Try logging out, clearing your browser cache, then logging back in. Or maybe try in a private/incognito session. Otherwise, it looks like you'll need to contact support.